# RPC connection errors(rate limits?)

Tags: rpc, wss

How to check the rate limits of concrete RPC?
It works until some time and then starts throwing an error. I suspect it's the rate limits

I connect to the remote node. For example `wss://acala-rpc.dwellir.com`.

It is interesting that when this RPC throws an error, all `wss://*-rpc.dwellir.com` throws the same error. So looks like it's some generic mechanism.  I assume it simply bans by IP.

With other remote RPC endpoints situation is the same.

These 2 logs are consecutive:

```
2022-10-09 19:27:04          API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: connection failed
2022-10-09 19:27:04          API-WS: disconnected from wss://acala-rpc.dwellir.com: 1006:: connection failed
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to check that with dwellir.com, your RPC provider. I don't think this rate limiting is enforced by Substrate itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you're at the behest of that service provider's internal logic of how they deal with load and spam - there is no set way to respond (e.g. if you 500 error, 404, actively ban ip, redirect it into a blackhole etc).

I'd recommend:

- use a throttle like [bottleneck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck) to prevent yourself from getting banned
- Not using the acala dwellir rpc endpoint, if i remember correctly, that one is highly limited
- writing some code (like a connection singleton) which reuses the same wss connection and reconnects to different endpoint if you're booted off